How do I get ssh-askpass working in Wayland, on KDE?
I'm trying out Wayland on KDE 6.1, to work around some other issues. I rely heavily on ssh-askpass for confirming use of ssh keys (for local pam and remote connections) and don't want to give this up.
ssh-add and ssh-agent fail to launch a GUI prompt ask expected and configured when using X11.
I got ssh-add to invoke ssh-askpass, specifically ksshaskpass but I'm now entirely unfamiliar with how to select a platform plugin for Qt tools.
Errors
When I run $ ssh-add -c ~/.ssh/keys/key1-id and $ ksshaskpass directly:
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display :0
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland, minimalegl, vkkhrdisplay, linuxfb, xcb, eglfs, vnc, wayland-egl, offscreen, minimal.

System
$ update-alternatives --list ssh-askpass
/usr/bin/ksshaskpass
/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass

$ ls -l /usr/bin/ssh-askpass /etc/alternatives/ssh-askpass
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 28 06:14 /etc/alternatives/ssh-askpass -> /usr/bin/ksshaskpass*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar 28 06:14 /usr/bin/ssh-askpass -> /etc/alternatives/ssh-askpass*

Environment

DISPLAY=:0
SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=[never|prefer|always]
(optional) SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ksshaskpass or SSH_ASKPASS=ksshaskpass

not needed if /usr/bin/ssh-askpass --...--> /usr/bin/ksshaskpass,
e.g. via /etc/alternatives/ssh-askpass
$ update-alternatives --list ssh-askpass


ssh-agent -c

SSH_AGENT_PID=...
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=...




Test with $ QT_QPA_PLATFORM="wayland" ksshaskpass.
If that works, export QT_QPA_PLATFORM="wayland" in your shell setup files, or possibly in the ssh-agent environment when first launching it.
Use
ksshaskpass/wayland appropriately invokes the prompt-for-password on first use, and prompt confirmation on subsequent uses.
Also note
keychain is a helpful package available in Debian/Ubuntu repos, from gentoo, which supports easy reuse of ssh (or gpg) sessions across individual logins, instead of hand-rolling this in login scripts and systemd units.
